# Почему не удается преобразовать из int в str?

Tags: c#

Почему не удается преобразовать из `int` в `str`?

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 15;
        int b = a;
        Console.WriteLine(a , b);   //появляется ошибка, что невозможно перевести переменную "а" в тип "str" 
    }
}
```

`a` и `b` по сути одно и то же, но при этом второе без ошибок удается выводить, а `a` нет.
То есть, это работает:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 15;
        int b = a;
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

А первая версия - нет

Comment: Потому что читайте [документацию WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-7.0) - когда аргументов несколько, первый аргумент всегда должен быть строкой, задающей формат вывода

Comment: Какой именно вариант должен использоваться? https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-7.0

Comment: Что вы ожидаете от `Console.WriteLine(a , b)`? Всегда пишите, какой результат ожидается, иначе сам вопрос не имеет смысла и будет закрыт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сегодня поработаю Вангой.

Смею предположить что имелось ввиду:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{a} , {b}");
```